# PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() , fakes database not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, foreach

I not sure why I am getting this warning from wordpress worked fine on local wamp settings its supposed to be a fake database. But its giving the foreach() error warning. Its just for training purposes.

```
<?php
// Fake database functions
// For demonstration purposes, it is not worth setting up a 

whole 
// database. So these functions will fake it by putting a 
// database-like associative array in the session.
// Obviously, in real life, you would use a database and 

remove
// this file.

**function initialize_fake_database()** {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['fake_database'])) {
        $users = [
          [
                'id' => 0, 
                'username' => 'kskoglund', 
                'hashed_password' => 

password_hash('secret', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
            ], [
                'id' => 1, 
                'username' => 'jsmith',
                'hashed_password' => 

password_hash('Never73#Guess', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
            ], [
                'id' => 2, 
                'username' => 'ljohnson',
                'hashed_password' => 

password_hash('Not+A+Password', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
            ], [
                'id' => 3, 
                'username' => 'abutcher',
                'hashed_password' => 

password_hash('wonderboy', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
            ] 
        ];
        $blacklisted_ips = [
            ['ip' => '5.5.5.5'], 
            ['ip' => '6.6.6.6'], 
            ['ip' => '7.7.7.7']
        ];
        // There are 3 fake tables in our fake 

database.
        $_SESSION['fake_database'] = [
            'users' => $users,
            'failed_logins' => [],
            'blacklisted_ips' => $blacklisted_ips
        ];
    }
}

function remove_fake_database() {
    $_SESSION['fake_database'] = null;
}

// Search our fake database $table for all records
// where the specified $key has the given $value.
// Returns an array, even if only one record is found.
function find_all_in_fake_db($table, $key, $value) {
    $fake_db = $_SESSION['fake_database'];
    $fake_table = $fake_db[$table];
    $results = [];
  **foreach($fake_table as $record) {
    if (isset($record[$key]) && $record[$key] == $value) {
            // This is a matching record, add it *

to results array
      $results[] = $record;*
    }
  }
  return $results;
}

// Returns first matching record or null
function find_one_in_fake_db($table, $key, $value) {
    $results = find_all_in_fake_db($table, $key, $value);
    $result = count($results) > 0 ? $results[0] : null;
  return $result;
}

// Add a new record to the specified fake table
function add_record_to_fake_db($table, $record) {
    $fake_db = $_SESSION['fake_database'];
    $fake_table = $fake_db[$table];

    $fake_table[] = $record;

    // replace old data with updated versions
    $fake_db[$table] = $fake_table;
    $_SESSION['fake_database'] = $fake_db;
    return true;
}

// Update an existing record in fake table
// You must specify the key used to identify the record
// to be updated.
function update_record_in_fake_db($table, $key, $new_record) {
    $fake_db = $_SESSION['fake_database'];
    $fake_table = $fake_db[$table];
    $value = $new_record[$key];

    // use a reference (&) so that the update happens to
    // the record in the table.
  foreach($fake_table as &$record) {
    if (isset($record[$key]) && $record[$key] == $value) {
      // This is the record to update
            $record = array_merge($record, 

$new_record);
    }
  }

    // replace old data with updated versions
    $fake_db[$table] = $fake_table;
    $_SESSION['fake_database'] = $fake_db;
    return true;
}

?>
```

Comment: Double check that $fake_table has a value and is an array.

Comment: post your error and the line

Comment: Where do you call initialize_fake_database()?

Comment: this is the line the error begins on  error is foreach invalid argument                                                foreach($fake_table as $record) {
    if (isset($record[$key]) && $record[$key] == $value) {

Comment: generally, foreach function show error warning if array parameter is empty, there's no array can be looping. so you can anticipate with checked if empty before.. `if(!empty($fake_table)){ 
foreach($fake_table as $record) {
    if (isset($record[$key]) && $record[$key] == $value) { /* bla bla bla */}
}
}else{
return false;
}`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash()     ***function initialize_fake_database()** {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['fake_database'])) {
        $users = [
          [
                'id' => 0, 
                'username' => 'kskoglund', 
                'hashed_password' => 

password_hash('secret', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)*

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the foreach error then i was using a older version of of php and had a password hash problem and used https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat to fix it.

```
if(!empty($fake_table)){ foreach($fake_table as $record) { if (isset($record[$key]) && $record[$key] == $value) { /* bla bla bla */} } }else{ return false; }
            // This is a matching record, add it to results array
      $results[] = $record;
    }

  return $results;
```